# Displaying ICS data in ExpressionEngine

Tags: calendar, ical

I'm trying to help out with a client that manages its own in-house web server, where iCal and BusyCal are used to maintain a dozen or so calendars. These calendars are displayed for members in a portal facilitated by ExpressionEngine.

The previous developer, who is frustratingly unavailable, hacked together an add-on that parses .ics files with [SG-iCalendar](https://github.com/fangel/SG-iCalendar), turns events into a JSON feed, and uses loads of JavaScript to render them in this portal. The result is a poorly-performing calendar that's now incorrectly rendering *some* recurring events depending on how they're defined in the ICS format.

Is there a better way to reliably display calendar events in the portal without requiring the client to change the way they currently manage events? iCal, BusyCal, and Outlook all do just fine rendering these calendars accurately – but I'm not sure what to advise to help the client away from this hack and *not* waste money having me re-invent the wheel with a new parser.

Answer (score 1):

[Easy iCalendar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/easy-icalendar)?

[SolSpace Calendar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/calendar) (hell of a price tag though!)

Note I've not used either so can't recommend and you'd need to explore further!

Comment: Thanks for the response, Peter. My impression is that Easy iCalendar is for exporting iCal files only, from data stored in ExpressionEngine. SolSpace Calendar says it can import ics data, but I've not used it either and it seems like it would prefer to be the grand manager of events itself.

Comment: I've used Solspace Calendar quite a lot. Never tried to import from ics into it though. It's a great add-on, though it's very complex to master.